# sendemail most recent file attachment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail

I am using sendemail to send a log report and file attachment from a number of cron jobs. everything is going perfectly but what I would like to do is to attach the  most recent file i.e. the newest file from the specific folder. Is there a command for this or a way to pipe the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the latest file in the current folder :

```
 $ ls -t | sed q
```

Comment: Finding the file in the terminal isn't the issue. I need to append a statement to find the latest file to a sendemail command after the "-a" option so this won't work

Comment: So use a **command substitution** and your problem will be solved

Comment: If you are not at all familiar with shell programming, asking for a single detail on a programming site is not the way to find a consultant to write the whole script for you.